# Insert text after specific nth character in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert extra text into a file path in excel vba, after every 7th "\" How should I do it?

update:

i have fields like this:

**M:\project\2017\project name\work\name\test.pdf**

I would like to update it to in:

**M:\project\2017\project name\work\name\testfolder\test.pdf**

Comment: Can you update your question with a specific example ?

Comment: Split -> Add -> Re-join ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to [Substitute()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) the `6th` occurence of `"\"` char in your string to `"\testfolder\"`

**Formula:**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","\testfolder\",6)
```

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub insert_text()

  text_0 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
  text_1 = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(text_0, "\", "\testfolder\", 6)

  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = text_1

End Sub
```

**Result Image:**

[image]